# Post/Get works with VS Development server but not with IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, iis, iis-7

I have created a web page using Asp.Net MVC 4 (VS2010 SP1, Windows 7). It also has an api through what I can make a search or upload something (data and files). When I deploy the page on the development server of VS2010 SP1, all works fine but when I select IIS (IIS7), the api does not work any more. The "IsSuccessStatusCode" seems to be false. But the page itself works and can be acessed from other machines.

This is the address I use for the inbuilt dev server: "http://localhost:56272/api/"
And this I use for IIS: "http://127.0.0.1/api/"

I have created a virtual directory for IIS (done by VS2010). Do I need to configure something in addition or could it be a routing problem that only exists for IIS?

This is my client side - class MyService - for the GET:

```
 public MyService(string serviceAdress) //"http://127.0.0.1/api/"
        {
            this.serviceAdress = new Uri(serviceAdress); //of type Uri
            client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }
    public Task<IEnumerable<Item>> SearchByTag(string tag)
    {
        client.BaseAddress = serviceAdress;
        var getStuffCall=client.GetAsync("Search/ByTag/" + tag);
        var r=getStuffCall.ContinueWith(
            t =>t.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode? (t.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Item>>().Result):new List<Item>()
            );
        return r;
    }
```

My server side looks like this:

```
public class SearchController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Shared.Item> ByTag(string search)
        {....}
    }
```

And this is the routing in WebApiConfig:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "SearchApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/Search/{action}/{search}",
            defaults: new
                          {
                              controller="Search"                                  
                          }
        );
```

Comment: Instead of "call failed", can u provide what the actual Http Response status code, message, etc. is?

Comment: I now managed to get the result message out of that call and it said something like "not found". The address for IIS was wrong. I forgot to add the name of my Virtual Folder. So your question was a good hint! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the user that web site and application pool have write permissions to the directory you're performing your upload to. In the development server, it doesn't come into play because that runs under your local (or domain) account which has normal privileges. IIS7 is running under a restricted user account, so its privileges must either be adjusted or the folder you're uploading to needs to include this user with write privileges.

Specific instructions for adjusting privileges can be found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979124

Comment: But then it should work for performing a search in the database using GET, right? Also client.GetAsynch(...) does not work for IIS but for the inbuilt server.

Comment: Is `http://127.0.0.1/api/` the address the AJAX call is using to perform the GET?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this for using IIS. (And "http://localhost:56272/api/" with the port for th inbuilt server which works.)

Comment: @Katharina: AJAX calls shouldn't go against 127.0.0.1. The calls should be relative to the website being used. While you might be accessing it by using the localhost address while you're on that machine, any remote call will certainly fail because 127.0.0.1 will always resolve to the client machine not the server.

Comment: What do you mean with "relative to the website"? How would such an address look like? The alternative that I see is to use my actual IP-address (as the server is my machine). But I guess this is not what you mean.

Comment: Your call should be simply calling `/api` instead of the fully qualified domain. The browser should be supplying the domain based on where the page was rendered from.

Comment: I have set the property "BaseAddress" of the object "HttpClient" with the ip before. But now I skip setting the base address at all and add "/api" to the address when calling "client.GetAsynch(...)" ? When I do that I get "An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set." when calling the GetAsynch-method.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're putting all of these items. You might want to post a little more of your client side code in addition to the full method for your server side piece.

Answer (score 0):

The address for IIS was wrong. Instead of "http://127.0.0.1/api/" it had to be "http://127.0.0.1/MyVirtualFolderSomething/api/".